# AVD Manager IceCreamSandwich x86 Image not available for download

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

In Android Studio 2.3 (Mac) in the AVD Manager the image for IceCreamSandwich (API15) is shown but not available to download.

[AVD Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOQZe.png)

Since I have to satisfy compatibility requirements for API15 how could I download that image or where could I find the right image?

Thanks!

Comment: Also images for API15 for other processor types then x86 are shown but not downloadable via AVD. Any reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found out myself: If your are missing a "Download" link next to one of the images offered in the AVD manager just increase the column size of the "Release Name" column. Then the download links should appear.

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb. Thank you for posting this!

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.